# Allow Facebook, Google, etc. (OpenID) login to my WordPress.com hosted private blog

Tags: authentication, openid, wordpress.com

Is it possible, if using a private, wordpress.com hosted blog, to allow users to login via Facebook, Google, Yahoo, or other OpenID providers?

We have a private blog, and we prefer that users not have to signup for yet-another account at WordPress.com, and instead could simply login using an account they already have.  Between Facebook, Google, Yahoo, and Microsoft, I think that nearly all of our readers would already have an account.

I see that there are a number of plugins that offer this functionality if you're self-hosting WordPress... but what if you're hosting at WordPress.com?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on Wordpress.com hosting. The "plugin" optionality is highly limited and curated on Wordpress.com - so to get a wider breadth of functionality, an upgrade to self-hosted WP is needed.